# Ajax Post to a different domain url , redirect to another url

Tags: javascript

I am supposed to call a third party vendor - Cybersource using their silent order post. The problem is that I have an accordion page which has 3 panes, Account creation, Service address and billing (on third pane).

I am trying make an ajax call from [http://mydomain/billing][1] TO [http://cybersource/silentorderpost/pay][1].

In the post parameters I am setting response url = [http://mydomain/billing][1] this is where CS will send the response back.

When the Ajax post goes from my website to CS website, I do not get a callback but the Cybersource post the response back to my website [http://mydomain/billing][1] and this reloads my whole accordion page which I am trying to avoid. I understand that During an Ajax call, the Ajax expects a response on the same domain as "Called webservice", i.e. my Ajax post expects that Cybersource will post the response on something like [http://cybersource/response][1]. However, CS posts or redirects the response to my website and this is probably the reason, I never get my callback. When the response is posted my whole accordion page reloads and this causes all sorts of issues.

My Code:

```
     function myFunction() {
        //document.getElementById("myForm1").submit();
        var http= new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/silent/pay";
        var params = document.getElementById("queryStr");
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.send(params);
        //Send the proper header information along with the request


        http.onreadystatechange = function() {//IT NEVER COMES BACK TO THIS SECTION
            if(http.readyState == 4) {
                alert(http.responseText);
                console.log("I came back");
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

`USING JQUERY:`

function myFunction() {
            //document.getElementById("myForm1").submit();
            var http= new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/silent/pay";
            var params = document.getElementById("queryStr");
            var jqxhr = $.post( url, function() {
                            alert( "success" );
                            })
                        .done(function() {
                            alert( "second success" );
                        })
                        .fail(function() {
                            alert( "error" );
                        })
                        .always(function() {
                            alert( "finished" );
                        });

// Set another completion function for the request above
                        jqxhr.always(function() {
                            alert( "second finished" );
                    });

        }

Any solutions?

Comment: it seems that you dont send the request, if you use native `XMLHttpRequest` object you need to call `xhr.send()` method after `xhr.open()`

Comment: @ArchLicher I tried with Jquery as well function myFunction() {
            //document.getElementById("myForm1").submit();  var http= new XMLHttpRequest();  var url = "https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/silent/pay"; var params = document.getElementById("queryStr");  var jqxhr = $.post( url, function() { alert( "success" );    })
                        .done(function() {
                            alert( "second success" );
                        })
                        .always(function() {
                            alert( "finished" );
                        });
 
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way out. On my form I added an iframe and now when I get a post response from CS, my page does not reload, instead the response is updated in the iframe.

```
   <form action="https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/silent/pay" method ="post" target="myIframe"> ..... </form>
    <iframe src="" name="myIframe"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST',url,true);
var params = document.getElementById("queryStr");
// you need to call this method: 
xhr.send(params);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    //return stuff
} else {
    //return stuff
}
}
```

just like i wrote in my comment, you also need to send your request to the server via `xmlhttprequestObject.send()` before the readystate can change.

greetings

Comment: It does not work. cybersource response has this code window.onload = function(){
        document.forms['custom_redirect'].submit();
    }                                                                                                                       and this basically forwards the response to my domain and I get error  XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/silent/pay. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when I integrate cyber source silent post order. I resolved it with form with hidden input fields to create the signature and invisible iframe as the target for my form.

Few things you need to take care while integrating cyber source silent post
1. Make sure you are passing all required fields
2.Generate unique application number and uuid otherwise cyber source will consider it as duplicate request
3.create the signature to make sure input fields are not tampered 
4.Dont use ajax to submit the request, in this case the call might ge success but cyber source will not call your customer post back URL that you configured for response.